# Import Spreadsheet into SQLite Database through OS X App

Tags: excel, macos, sqlite, csv, numbers

I have a dataset which is only available as a downloadable spreadsheet and I want a to be able to extract the data from the spreadsheet and insert it into my database. I usually do such things by first converting to CSV and then importing into the database but this time I want to be able to do it automatically (as to be able to perform automatic updates to the database when a new  version of the spreadsheet is available), any ideas how to do this using techniques compatible with OS X (i.e. C/C++/Obj-C/AppleScript/Automator etc)

Comment: Are you asking us to write all the code for you, or are you searching for a library?

Comment: A library or API and maybe some code snippets